# missing user profiles in Manage Profile

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile

i have created 11 user profiles using powershell scripts from [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/769109/Add-User-Profiles-in-SharePoint-using-PowerShell-S).

but were unable to see the user profiles created in the Manage User Profile as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Try searching for them with 'Find profiles'. The list is empty until you search for a specific profile. You can search on accountname and preferred name.

Comment: HAHA. ok. anyway on a side note do i need to do a profile sync after creating user profile to see them?

Comment: apparantly, you have to search for the user profile i 'Find profiles' before any will show up

Comment: is there a way to display all user profile? like typing " * " in the Find Profiles?

Comment: You can try searching for the domain part of the usernames. But mind you, the results are limited to 50 max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to type in search query in the `Find profiles field` and click Find in order to see any profiles.

`*` is not possible, but if you type in part of the domain, you should get all users, e.g., if user accounts are `DOMAIN\user`, you could search with `DOMAIN` to get all users. Pretty close to `*`, I'd say.